# Issue with installing angularjs version of ng-infinite scroll using npm pacakge manager

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, npm-install

I'm using npm package manager to install dependencies in my application. I've listed all the required dependencies in package.json file. I've just added a new dependency for ng-infinite-scroll and I want this to be a js version, but when I ran the npm it installed the cofeescript version of it. How do I specify in my package.json to pick js version of it....any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

I just ran:

```
npm install --save ng-infinite-scroll@1.3.0
```

and it worked!. True it did bring in "inifinite-scroll.coffee", but it also brought in the javascript file.

**JS File Location**

> ng-infinite-scroll \ build \ ng-inifinite-scroll.js

**package.json**

```
"ng-infinite-scroll": "1.3.0"
```

Comment: Yeah, I did figure that out. Sorry, should've added a comment on my post.